# Show that 1 is adherent to the set $0<x<1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know the definition of an adherent point is: a is adherent to a set S if given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $x\in S$ such that $|x-a|<\epsilon$.

Intuitively, 1 must be adherent to $S$ since we can get arbitrarily close to it however I am not able to show this with any rigor.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it directly with the definition :
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We want a $x \in (0,1)$ such that $|x-1| < \varepsilon$.
We can take $x= 1 - \frac\varepsilon 2$. Then
$$|x-1| = \left|1 - \frac\varepsilon 2 - 1\right| = \frac\varepsilon 2 < \varepsilon$$

Comment: but what if ϵ/2>1? Then x is not in S?

Comment: If $\frac\varepsilon 2 > 1$, then I think you can find another $x$ working. The "hard" part is for small $\varepsilon$s.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $x=1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. We have $x\in (0,1)$ and $|x-1|=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: but what if  $\epsilon/2>1$? Then x is not in S?

Comment: You can assume without loss of generality that $\varepsilon /2<1$, because if an $x$ exists for $\varepsilon < 1/2$, it'll also exist for larger $\eta >\varepsilon$, as $\{x,\, |x-1|<\varepsilon\}\subset\{x,\, |x-1|<\eta\}$

Comment: But isn't the definition, given ANY positive epsilon... If $\epsilon = 100$ for example then the argument does not work, but if that is the case then choosing any element from S will work.

Comment: In this case, I define $x=1-\frac{\varepsilon '}{2}$ with $\varepsilon '<\frac{1}{2}$ and I write $|x-1|<\varepsilon '<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @dable: The definition is that given any positive $\varepsilon$, such an $x$ *must exist*.  But it doesn't have to be specifically $x = 1-\varepsilon/2$.  If it makes things clearer, we can let $x = 1-\min\{\varepsilon, 1\}/2$ and then the problem is solved.

Comment: @dable: Furthermore, as Kevin Quirin points out, the point of the definition is to show that the adherence holds in the limit as $\varepsilon$ approaches $0$ (but never reaches it).  Your observation is quite right, and to be rigorous should be accounted for.  In many cases, such a problem is not obvious and should be accounted for even in a casual way.  But in this instance, the resolution is fairly clear, once you've gotten the hang of things.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to yours. Here is an answer that satisfied me. I am using the definition of adherent point in which a point $b$ is adherent to $X$ if there exists a $y \in X$ such that $|b-y| \leq \epsilon$. However, it should be adaptable to your definition as well.

Proof:
Suppose towards contradiction that $b$ is not adherent to $(a,b)$. Then, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in (a,b)$ one has $|b-y| > \epsilon$. By trichotomy either $\epsilon < b-a$ or $\epsilon \geq b-a$. If $\epsilon < b-a$, then let $y = b-\epsilon$ (note that $y \in (a,b)$). Thus, $|b-y| = \epsilon$. Contradiction. If $\epsilon \geq b-a$ let $y = (b+a)/2$ (again note that $y \in (a,b)$). Then, $|b-y| = |(b-a)/2| < \epsilon$. Contradiction. Therefore, $b$ must be an adherent point of $(a,b)$.